# Prevent the cell before moving to another clicked cell in kendo grid incell editing

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo MVC grid with incell edit mode which is displaying few users records with their time sheets.

for my grid while editing , i have few conditions to validate. suppose a column should not exceed max 100 for users.
here is my requirement.
when am modifying values for particular user , in grid cellclose event am getting all records for that user and calculating sum column wise. if that column exceeds 100 then i want to prevent the user and untill and unless he modified values to become 100. if it exceeds 100 then he cont able to select another cell untill and unless he modifies the cell value and cound should lessthan or equal to 100. ( eg:  consider Jun column  for A user the count of june is greter than 100. so user has to modify that value to 10 then the sum of jun column for A user is 100)

grid.editCell is getting error is invalid function.

Nane Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec

A     20  30  50  70  80  90  30  50  65  55  45  48

A     20  35  56  57  28  90  30  50  65  95  35  18

B     20  30  50  70  80  90  30  50  65  55  45  48

B     20  35  56  57  28  90  30  50  65  95  35  18

here is my  code.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {

        var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.bind("cellClose", grid_cellClose);
        function grid_cellClose(e) {
            /* The result can be observed in the DevTools(F12) console of the browser. */
            var dataSource = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
            var _flt = { field: "EmpNumber", operator: "eq", value: e.model.EmpNumber };

            var copyDataSource = kendo.data.DataSource.create({
                data: dataSource.data()
            });
            copyDataSource.filter(_flt);

            var SumofMonth = 0;
            var columnName = CurrentEditCell;
            for (var index = 0; index < copyDataSource._view.length; index++) {
                SumofMonth += parseInt(copyDataSource._view[index][columnName]);
            };
            if (columnName == "Jan_F" || columnName == "Apr_F" || columnName == "Jul_F" || columnName == "Oct_F") {
                if (SumofMonth > 150) {
                    
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var focusedCellIndex = this.current()[0].cellIndex;
                    var focusedCell = $("#grid tr[data-uid='" + e.model.uid + "'] td:nth-child(" + (focusedCellIndex + 1) + ")");
                    grid.select(focusedCell);
                    //grid.editCell(focusedCell);
                }
            }
            if (columnName == "Feb_F" || columnName == "Mar_F" || columnName == "May_F" || columnName == "Jun_F" || columnName == "Aug_F" || columnName == "Sep_F" || columnName == "Nov_F" || columnName == "Dec_F") {
                if (SumofMonth > 100) {
                   
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var focusedCellIndex = this.current()[0].cellIndex;
                    var focusedCell = $("#grid tr[data-uid='" + e.model.uid + "'] td:nth-child(" + (focusedCellIndex + 1) + ")");
                    grid.select(focusedCell);
                    //grid.editCell(focusedCell);
                }
            }


        }
        });
```